# yo webapp generator is installed but not recognized?

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I try to install the webapp generator from yeoman but I have got this error :

> You don't seem to have a generator with the name webapp installed.

after `yo webapp` :

```
npm install -g yo (works fine)
npm install -g generator-webapp (works fine)
yo webapp (does not work)
```

---

Here is the command lines (on Mac Os) :

```
MBP-de-Empon:yo Empon$ npm install -g yo
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
/Users/Empon/npm/bin/yo-complete -> /Users/Empon/npm/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/completion/index.js
/Users/Empon/npm/bin/yo -> /Users/Empon/npm/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js

> yo@1.8.5 postinstall /Users/Empon/npm/lib/node_modules/yo
> yodoctor


Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

✔ Global configuration file is valid
✔ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
✔ Node.js version
✔ No .bowerrc file in home directory
✔ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
✔ npm version

Everything looks all right!
/Users/Empon/npm/lib
└── yo@1.8.5 

MBP-de-Empon:yo Empon$ npm install -g generator-webapp
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
/Users/Empon/npm/lib
└── generator-webapp@2.4.1 

MBP-de-Empon:yo Empon$ yo webapp
Error webapp 

You don't seem to have a generator with the name webapp installed.
You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
To see the 14 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.
MBP-de-Empon:yo Empon$
```

---

EDIT :
So yeoman searched at `usr/local...` and the webapp generator was downloaded at `/Users/Empon/...`

So I copied the content into a new folder with the same name : `generator-webapp`:

`mkdir generator-webapp`

`cp -a /Users/Empon/npm/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/. /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/`

I tried again `yo webapp`, and I have got this error now :

So it looks good until this line :

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

and a new line appear on the Terminal and I was not being able to complete the sass options :

```
MBP-de-Empon:yo Empon$ yo webapp

     _-----_     ╭──────────────────────────╮
    |       |    │  'Allo 'allo! Out of the │
    |--(o)--|    │    box I include HTML5   │
   `---------´   │ Boilerplate, jQuery, and │
    ( _´U`_ )    │ a gulpfile to build your │
    /___A___\   /│           app.           │
     |  ~  |     ╰──────────────────────────╯
   __'.___.'__   
 ´   `  |° ´ Y ` 

? Which additional features would you like to include? (Press <space> to select)
❯◉ Sass
 ◉ Bootstrap
 ◉ Modernizr

events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: this.env.adapter.prompt(...).then is not a function
    at Base.prompt (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:240:45)
    at module.exports.generators.Base.extend.prompting (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/app/index.js:102:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:439:23)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/run-async/index.js:25:25
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/run-async/index.js:24:19
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:440:9
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
MBP-de-Empon:yo Empon$
```

Comment: Try running `DEBUG=yeoman:* yo webapp` and see where Yeoman search for generators.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias thanks, I edited my post with some changes, could you have a look?

Comment: So it looks like you have multiples versions of NPM installed. Copying the folder manually might not work - as you saw. Fix your npm then reinstall yo and your generators.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias thanks, it works, although I had to remove manually `/Users/Empon/.npmrc` and while I reinstalled yeoman I could see a path like `/Users/Empon/.npm`, so I don't know if everything is correctly removed... but the three lines to make yeoman start work now. So thanks a lot ;-)